# a program discovering himself how to solve propositional calculus

Tags: artificial-intelligence, first-order-logic, propositional-logic

it is well-known that [propositional logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) problems such as

$$ (p\leftrightarrow q)  \lor r \quad\overset{?}{\vdash}\quad (((p\lor q)\to(p\land q)) \land \lnot r)\lor r$$

can be simply solved by evaluating the corresponding [boolean functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_function) for the $2^n$ possible values of the $n$ boolean variables (here $p,q,r$).

my question is then : instead of hand-writing such a propositional logic solver, couldn't we search for a program capable of generating such a solver ?

what would be then the minimal core / set of concepts and rules needed for a program being capable of ''discovering'' and ''solving'' the propositional calculus ?

is it a unsolvable artificial intelligence problem, or would it have some nice solutions, helpful for solving the more interesting [higher order logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) ?

Comment: No, this is not how artificial intelligence works.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : do you have some precision on your comment, or is it only a general statement that what we call "AI" is until now more about statistical machine learning than artificial intelligence ?

Comment: What you describe is at the moment very much out of reach. It's more like science fiction.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : you know that solving the propositional calculus is really not complicated, and that the automatic theorem provers can solve some quite complicated problems, hence I don't think it is out of reach, it is just that we don't know yet how to do it, but it doesn't have to be so complicated compared to what we already do

Comment: I think to it as one of the simplest possible meta-maths problems, and as a first (small) step toward a mathematician AI

Comment: I suggest you study state of the art AI before describing its potential marvels.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : I know already quite a lot, but not everything. what are you thinking about ?

Comment: and it seems like you don't make the difference between propositional calculus and predicate logic. the former is only for boolean functions, while the latter for all the arithmetic (hence a huge part of the mathematics).

Comment: I guess we will just have to disagree.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  disagree on what ?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : if finally you recall something in the state of art of AI being related to my question, do not hesitate to tell me

Comment: Nothing similar to your fantasy exists in state of the art AI. That's the problem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : the truth is that you didn't understand my question ... ! it is about the possible proofs that any propositional logic theorem can be proved by the mean of a simple algorithm computing the $2^n$ values of a $n$ variable boolean function. my question is about writing a program finding itself one of those proof (what any automatic theorem prover can do without much difficulty) and using it to prove any propositional calculus "theorem" we'd like. it is a toy model for an automatic theorem prover : what is the minimal program / set of axioms and rules we need for all this.

Comment: It is unclear which input you would be allowed to provide to this program in order to teach it the task.

Comment: Could you clarify your question to tell us what would be allowed to generate a program that discovers the *and* logical operator ?

Answer (score 2):

If there are no quantifiers, testing validity of such formulas is equivalent to testing satisfiability of the complement of the formula.  That can be done with a SAT solver.  SAT solvers and the satisfiability problem are well-studied.  So, the minimal set of concepts needed would be: enough to solve SAT.

Statements with quantifiers are harder (QBF).  Higher-order logics are harder still.

Comment: I don't see how SAT problems which are $$\exists x_1,\ldots,x_n \quad P(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$$ (so they are $1$st order logic, not propositional logic) are related to my question which is about how generating automatically an algorithm for solving propositional calculus problems

Comment: in fact, SAT solvers are much more than that : they take in account the time and space complexity needed to solve the $\exists x, P(x)$ problem, and try to generate an algorithm for solving it as fast as possible. whereas what I meant in my question is generating a simple propositional logic solver, which doesn't care of how much time will be needed, as far as it is finite (so testing the $2^n$ possible values of $x$ is not a problem), do you see what I mean ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how you would define success, but here are a couple of references and some context to help you get started.

Have a look at this paper in the AI Journal:

[A computational approach to George Boole’s discovery of Mathematical Logic](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370297000179)

The underlying approach to be seems to be an old-fashioned production system.

I would be remiss if I didn't mention the now ancient Automated Mathematician program by Lenat. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Mathematician) gives a good overview of the program as well as its considerable shortcomings. Nice related references there as well.

Finally, here's a recent [New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/07/02/science/ai-mathematics-machine-learning.html) that might be relevant.